# Scala MongoDB Casbah need to build a dynamic $or query

Tags: casbah, mongodb-scala

Using Scala, MongoDB, Casbah.

Given a random list of strings:

```
  val names = {
    val listBuffer = new ListBuffer[String]
    for(n <- 1 to (new Random().nextInt(5) + 1)){
      val name = ((new Random().nextInt(26) + 65).asInstanceOf[Char]).toString
      listBuffer += name
    }
    listBuffer.toList
  }
```

Given a MongoDB document structure:

```
"_id": <uuid>  
"name": <string>
```

How do I find all documents that have a name equal to an entry in my list using a single **single** MongoDBCollection.find() statement? (i.e using $or)

Thanks,
- Don

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB has conditional operator `$in` that lets test if a field's value is in a list of values ([documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24in))

```
collection.find({name: {$in: ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]}})
```

In Casbah this will look like

```
collection.find("name" $in names)
```

Comment: In order for this to work, you must:

import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._